# How can I fetch data for future dates in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database

I want to get the future game playing date. Field **game_date** is in format of **d/m/Y** and data type is **varchar**.

I am running this query. There are records available in the database but this query isn't fetching any data. Please help

**Query**

```
SELECT * FROM dx_scores
WHERE
    t_name='Team 11'
    and username='joe@example.com'
    and STR_TO_DATE(game_date, '%d/%m/%Y' ) >= CURDATE();
```

Comment: make sure future data for given where condition is available in `DATABASE`

Comment: wouldn't be easier to change the data type?

Answer (score 1):

Please try this query

```
SELECT * FROM dx_scores WHERE t_name='Team 11' and username='joe@example.com' and DATE(game_date, '%d/%m/%Y' ) >=  DATE(CURDATE());
```